# VBA Code Fix for Moving row from one table to another based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

*Edit - I added the text code for my second attempt and updated the worksheet rows based on BlackCat's recommendation. Still, it is adding the row to the end after my table instead of in my table. [Here's a link to my excel spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mDYt43jtdmA_p1kCIdpD-jhmHtkAMqzv/view?usp=sharing)

I am wanting to move rows automatically using VBA code from one table to another table in another tab in my excel workbook.

My first tab is called "Current Projects" with a 4th column called "Status". This table has about 21 columns and is updated regularily. When I select the status as "Completed" or "Cancelled", I would like the VBA code to immediately run and essentially "cut" that row and copy it in its entirety (all 21 columns of information for that tow) to another tab called "Archive" using the next empty row in that existing table (so it does not overwrite any existing data already in the table).

I am very new to VBA coding and have tried the two following options I found on the internet but both have given errors or not done what I need. I think it may be also my fault for not knowing how to plug in my information into the codes I am finding on the internet so any explanations on that would also be nice to know so I can learn what I did wrong.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

First Try:
In Sheet Code - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGxyF.png)
This didn't work, I think because of something in the highlighted portion and gave a subscript out of range error

Second Try:
2 Modules Created:
Module 1

Sub MoveBased2OnValue()

```
Dim xRg As Range

Dim xCell As Range

Dim A As Long

Dim B As Long

Dim C As Long

A = Worksheets("Current Projects").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

B = Worksheets("Archive").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If B = 1 Then

   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0

End If

Set xRg = Worksheets("Current Projects").Range("D1:D" & A)

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For C = 1 To xRg.Count

    If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Completed" Then

        Set rowx = Worksheets("Archive").AutoFilter.Range
        rowx.AutoFilter
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & B + 1)
        rowx.AutoFilter

        xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete

        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Completed" Then

            C = C - 1

        End If

        B = B + 1

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Module 2

Sub MoveBasedOnValue()

```
Dim xRg As Range

Dim xCell As Range

Dim A As Long

Dim B As Long

Dim C As Long

A = Worksheets("Current Projects").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

B = Worksheets("Archive").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If B = 1 Then

   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0

End If

Set xRg = Worksheets("Current Projects").Range("D1:D" & A)

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For C = 1 To xRg.Count

    If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Cancelled" Then

        Set rowx = Worksheets("Archive").AutoFilter.Range
        rowx.AutoFilter
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & B + 1)
        rowx.AutoFilter

        xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete

        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Cancelled" Then

            C = C - 1

        End If

        B = B + 1

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

And a Sheet Code -

```
    Dim Z As Long

    Dim xVal As String

    On Error Resume Next

    If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Z = 1 To Target.Count

        If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then

            Call MoveBasedOnValue

            Call MoveBased2OnValue

        End If

    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This did all the necessary stuff (cut the row when I selected Completed or Cancelled and added it to the Archive tab) BUT it would add the row at the end of the table and not to the existing table which I need it to do as I have some other formulas already in the worksheet that rely on the data being in a table format

Comment: Please never, ever post code as an image. Always post code as text.

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` hide the run-time errors in your code. Delete if not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

update, converted back into change event with adding copied row to table "tblArchive"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim wsArchive As Worksheet
    Dim tblArchive As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheets to the respective sheets
    Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Projects")
    Set wsArchive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive")
    
    ' Check if the change occurred in column D of the "Current Projects" sheet
    If Not Intersect(Target, wsCurrent.Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent triggering the event again
        
        ' Set the tblArchive as the "tblArchive" table in the "Archive" sheet
        Set tblArchive = wsArchive.ListObjects("tblArchive")
        
        ' Loop through the changed cells in column D
        For Each cell In Target
            ' Check if the cell value is "Completed" or "Cancelled"
            If cell.Value = "Completed" Or cell.Value = "Cancelled" Then
                ' Insert a new row at the end of the tblArchive table
                Set newRow = tblArchive.ListRows.Add
                
                ' Copy specific columns (A to AJ) and paste values into the new row of the tblArchive table
                wsCurrent.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":AJ" & cell.Row).Copy
                newRow.Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the clipboard
                wsCurrent.Rows(cell.Row).Delete ' Delete the row from the "Current Projects" sheet
            End If
        Next cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable events back
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I tried this code and it said there was an error with the this part "  cell.EntireRow.Cut wsArchive.Cells(lastRow, "A")" - I am sorry but I don't know how to troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: @PrincessT does the row that needs to be copied contains formulas? also can you describe the error label that is displayed?

Comment: @PrincessT see updated code above

Comment: Yes the row that needs to be copied contains formulas. I just tried using the one you put above - it works like my second attempt but two issues: It doesn't at it to the table, just puts it as a new row after the table and two, it doesn't move it over automatically when I select Cancelled or Completed, I have to manually run it.

Comment: @PrincessT see updated code above, put the worksheet change sub inside sheet `Current Projects`

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work as the smoothest solutions so I will use this going forward! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @PrincessT If the provided code successfully addresses your issue, it would be beneficial to designate it as the answer to assist others encountering the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be that in the code of the Second Try the determining of the last filled row is defined with UsedRange property. But this property can return sometimes false value because of the (e.g.) previous data formatting of the cells on the sheet.
To get the correct row or column index of the last used cell

- search only the column or row which need
- use the End property

something like this

```
Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row            'last occupied row in column=F
Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column     'last occupied column in row=4
```

After edit the question. In both Sub insert instead

```
A = Worksheets("Current Projects").UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

this

```
A = Worksheets("Current Projects").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
B = Worksheets("Archive").Range("D" & Worksheets("Current Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

and instead

```
Set rowx = Worksheets("Archive").AutoFilter.Range
        rowx.AutoFilter
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & B + 1)
        rowx.AutoFilter
```

this

```
Worksheets("Archive").ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & B + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Black Cat, I change the two rows you asked me to, so now the modules look like the above, but it is still putting the row at the end of my table instead of IN the table

Comment: @Princess According to your image it's an autofiltered table. If you add a new row to the worksheet, the Filtered range also has to increased one. This can be done manually or in VBA. See my edit.

Comment: I made the addition to the code and updated the above but it is still adding it outside of my table instead of inside of it

Comment: @Princess My last attempt for today. Pls. see edit (rowx.Resize(1).AutoFilter)

Comment: Tried the update as well and still not adding to the table - I really appreciate you continuing to try and help me! I am going to clear out the sensitive data and add the excel workbook to my request in case this helps!

Comment: @Princess After the attached workbook, this try.

Comment: I tried this new code, and it did successfully work for the first project but when I attempted to select a second project status excel crashes and restarts each time and I am unable to do it more than once.

Comment: @Princess Debug the two Subs step-by-step, inactivate On Error Resume Next , at which line crashes, and was any error message during debug?